# How to send function output to a table cell in JS/HTML?

Tags: javascript, function, output

Beginner programmer here, I am trying to create an application that involves sending the output of a function to a table cell. Not really sure where to start with this, I've made a button that calls the function when clicked but that's it.

I'm sure there are many steps here and I am not expecting a full step by step tutorial but as I said I am a beginner designing my first app so if anyone could just point me in the right direction as to what to research, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id ="name"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can store the value from the function in a variable and insert it into the cell using the following JS line:

```
value = function();
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = value;
```

Hope this helps you!!